# Creating a simple hashtag formatter in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is it possible, without using external libraries, to parse a string with hashtag then style it with the `Text` component?

```js
const string = "Let's #Tweet on #Twitter";

// Expect:
// Let's <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>#Tweet</Text> on <Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>#Twitter</Text>
```

I thought this would do:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native';

export const HASHTAG_FORMATTER = string => {
  return string.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, `$1${<Text style={{ color: 'blue' }}>$2</Text>}`);
}
```

Usage:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { HASHTAG_FORMATTER } from '../../utilities/hashtag';

const Home = props => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{HASHTAG_FORMATTER("Let's #Tweet on #Twitter")}</Text>
    <View>
  )
}
```

What I got instead was:

> Let's [object Object] on [object Object]

See example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-69dwm?fontsize=14

Is there a way to achieve this in jsx? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use back references like this, you can use callback function of replace when you want to have a dynamic evaluation

```js
const HASHTAG_FORMATTER = string => {
  return string.replace(/(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig, (m, g1, g2) => {
    return g1 + "<span style={color:'green'}>" + g2 + "< /span>"
  });
}


console.log(HASHTAG_FORMATTER("#tweet"))
```

To solve your specific problem you need to solve it by splitting string and then building Text components as per the values

[`Demo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-ud4wq)

```
const HASHTAG_FORMATTER = string => {
  return string.split(/((?:^|\s)(?:#[a-z\d-]+))/gi).filter(Boolean).map((v,i)=>{
    if(v.includes('#')){
      return <Text key={i} style={{color:'green'}}>{v}</Text>
    }   else{
      return <Text key={i}>{v}</Text>
    }
  })
};
```

Comment: Thanks but this wont work in React Native. The entire output is seen as a string. Also, "span" should be `Text` component.

Comment: @Sylar span is just for demonstration purpose, can you post a fiddle i can see how to do it specifically for react native

Comment: @Sylar you can see [`this demo`](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-mmt0m) you can do something like this

Answer (score 0):

Now you can handle @Mention and #hashtag handle Code snippet

```
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

const HASHTAG_FORMATTER = string => {
  return string.split(/((?:^|\s)(?:#[a-z\d-] || @[a-z\d-]+))/gi).filter(Boolean).map((v,i)=>{
    if(v.includes('#') || v.includes('@')){
      return <Text key={i} onPress={()=>{alert(v)}} style={{color:'green'}}>{v}</Text>
    }  else{
      return <Text key={i}>{v}</Text>
    }
  })
};

const App =()=> {
    return (
      <View style={styles.app}>
        <Text>{HASHTAG_FORMATTER("Let's #Tweet on #Twitter by @pakistan")}</Text>
      </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginTop: 100,
    maxWidth: 500
  }
});

export default App;
```